# unable to install tree with brew in macBook bro M2

Tags: linux, mac, operating-systems, tree

I am trying to install tree command on my MacBook pro M2 machine but seems like brew is not working

> > brew install tree
> > Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!
> > Please create a new installation in /opt/homebrew using one of the
> > "Alternative Installs" from:
> > https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
> > You can migrate your previously installed formula list with:
> > brew bundle dump

Comment: Does Brew support the M1 processor? Does the version of Brew you've installed support the M1 processor? Have you followed this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66666134/how-to-install-homebrew-on-m1-mac

Comment: @music2myear sorry its M2 I have updated my question. I am using brew to install other packages/tool but tree is not working.